# Angular Unit Testing - Mock Child Component using Stub

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to unit test a component that has a child component that I want to mock. I don't want to use the NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA cause the drawbacks associated. I am trying to use a stub/dummy child component. The code is as follows:

**parent.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
    <!-- Does other things -->
    <child></child>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent { }
```

**child.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: '<!-- Does something -->'
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() input1: string;
  @Input() input2?: number;
}
```

**parent.component.spec.ts**

```
describe('ParentComponent', () => {
  let component: ParentComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ParentComponent>;
  let router: Router;

  @Component({
    selector: 'child',
    template: '<div></div>'
  })
  class ChildStubComponent {
    @Input() input1: string;
    @Input() input2: number;
  }

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ParentComponent, ChildStubComponent ],
      imports: [
        AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule, BrowserAnimationsModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes)
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    spyOnProperty(router, 'url', 'get').and.returnValue('/somePath');
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The problem I'm having is that angular is complaining with the following error:

```
Failed: Template parse errors:
More than one component matched on this element.
Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element.
```

I'm using Angular version 8 if that helps. Everywhere I looked so far shows that you stub a child component the same way I am doing now. Using ngMocks is not an option at the moment.

**EDIT**
Tried using ngMock but this only has the same problem. Any help would be very much appreciated!

**Solution**

Got it working. Problem was that the AppRoutingModule had the real component imported already.

Comment: You probably already declared the (real) child component in your AppRoutingModule.

Comment: Is it possible to import the module without that component in there just for testing?

Comment: You can probably do it using https://angular.io/api/core/testing/TestBed#overrideModule. But I would just avoid importing this module in the first place. Import/declare just what you need in your testing module.

Comment: Awesome! I got it working. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the nested component, we can mock them like this: https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#stubbing-unneeded-components

In conclusion, your **parent.component.spec.ts** should be:

```
import { HttpClientTestingModule} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

describe('ParentComponent', () => {
  let component: ParentComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ParentComponent>;
  let router: Router;


 @Component({selector: 'child', template: ''})
 class ChildStubComponent {}

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ParentComponent, ChildStubComponent ],
      imports: [
        AppRoutingModule, HttpClientTestingModule, BrowserAnimationsModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes(routes)
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ParentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    router = TestBed.get(Router);
    spyOnProperty(router, 'url', 'get').and.returnValue('/somePath');
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```